# No touchesbegan: in live camera area of UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

in my UIImagePickerController (camera shooting view), I want to track touches.
Every touch event gets properly called except for touchesbegan:

It's not a typo or something because touchesbegan: had been called up to the moment,
I've changed the controller from UIViewController to UIImagePickerController.

Why is touchesbegan: not called in UIImagePickerController?
How do I achieve this?

---

Update: It works. But only on the controls (which are located at the bottom). It doesn't work in the camera live picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a transparent view over the preview area, subclass UIView and capture touch events there?